# Docker should trigger common rest call when container is created

Tags: docker

I am beginner in docker.I want to know something, whenever we execute run command or container is created. I want to trigger or call a common rest call where I will have the container id and some other information. How can we do that? When I will know that container is created at same time I want to trigger the common rest call.﻿Where should I do code in docker which can invoke my rest call through which I can send the Container information to the data base? 
How can we make a common docker file which will be invoked every time whenever docker container is created.
I want to do all these process in Java and MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider whether an off-the-shelf service like [Consul](https://consul.io) that manages service discovery, or a heavier-weight deployment system like [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io), might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi David,
Thank you for the reply. But I am looking answer only for docker as it is the requirement. Can't we do this in docker?

Comment: Not natively.  You might look up the "registration sidecar" concept.  You can of course patch your images to do this, but they'll only be usable in your specific environment (this might be a problem for developers) and might not be able to get the metadata you're after.